# Have to execute 10000+ SQL queries on DB using Python and Multithreading

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I have to execute lots of SQL queries from a DB parallelly using Multithreading in Python. Following is the code which I'm trying to execute but didn't got any significant time improvements.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys
import psycopg2
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from threading import Thread

db_conn = psycopg2.connect("host="+db_host+" port="+str(db_port)+" user="+db_username+" password="+db_password+" dbname="+db_name)


def db_query(script):
    df = pd.read_sql_query(script, db_conn)
    return df


def listofRowsfetchall(cursor):
    return [
        list(row)
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

def listfetchall(cursor):
    return [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

db_cur = db_conn.cursor()


# Date range within which data will be extracted
strt_date = str(date(2019,1,1))
end_date = str(datetime.date(datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1)))

result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[c1,c2,c3,c4...])


def execute_sql_script(i, org_id,strt_date, end_date):
    t1 = time.time()
    print(i, "Started")
    global track_org
    head = ['chart_id', 'x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2', 'filter_1']
    print(track_org.columns)

    # Query 1
    script = '''SOME SQL QUERY'''%(org_id, strt_date, end_date)
    
    DF1 = db_query(script)
    result_df.append(DF1)


    #QUERY 2
    script1 = '''SOME SQL QUERY'''%(org_id, strt_date, end_date)

    DF2 = db_query(script1)
    result_df.append(DF2)


    #QUERY 3
    script3 = '''SOME SQL QUERY'''%(org_id, strt_date, end_date)

    DF3 = db_query(script3)
    result_df.append(DF3)

    t2 = time.time()

    print(str(i)+' execution time', t2-t1) # Time of ith Org Sql execution


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    df = pd.read_csv('ORG_FILE.csv')
    orgs = list(df['org_id'])

    max_threads = 2000

    for t in range(5):
        threads = []

        for i, org_id in enumerate(orgs[t*max_threads: (t+1)*max_threads]):
            if org_id.isalnum():
                t = Thread(target=execute_sql_script, args=(i, org_id, strt_date, end_date, ))
                threads.append(t)
        
        for t in threads:
            t.start()

        for t in threads:
            t.join()
    
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Data processing time of all query : "+str(end_time-start_time)+' seconds')
```

Here without using Threading and doing execution in sequential manner took total 2.5 hours for execution but using Threading total time was 1.75 hours. Whether each Org's execution time is around 1-2 minutes. What is that I'm doing wrong here??

Regards
Vishal

Comment: have you profiled your code?  Your performance limit might be coming from elsewhere

Comment: Without profiling, I can say that you're mixing I/O-bound ops with CPU-bound ops in your threads. I/O-bound should use threads, CPU-bound should use processes. Querying the DB is I/O-bound, while processing the results of said query are CPU-bound.

Comment: Can you guys please tell me how to profile my code?